# fetch api and proxies

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

`

```
const HttpProxyAgent = require('http-proxy-agent');
async function run () {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, slowMo: 10});
    page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setRequestInterception(true);
    var Agent = new HttpProxyAgent('http://user:pass@ip:port');

    await page.evaluate((Agent) => {
        fetch('https://api.ipify.org?format=json', {agent: Agent}).then(response => response.json()).then(data => console.log(data))
    })
```

`

The result is my real IP, instead of the proxy's.
And I don't think there's anything wrong with my code, so could it be that fetch just refuses to use proxies?

Comment: Are you using node-fetch?

Comment: No I'm using the normal fetch API, inside `page.evaluate` in puppeteer.

Comment: Probably it doesn't work with native fetch, only with node-fetch. Have you tried this one https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/678 to set proxy for a page?

Comment: Or even for a browser instance, like this: `const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, slowMo: 10, args: [ '--proxy-server=127.0.0.1:9876' ] });`

Comment: Hmm okay I'm going to try some solutions in the github issue you posted, thanks

Comment: no problem, let me know how it goes!